# Capturing row number when Enter pressed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a tracker sheet for work done during a shutdown. Basically, on the relevant row, people change a status, put a comment in, their name and then the date. When they press Enter on the date cell, I have a Worksheet_Change event to copy the entered 3 cells to another sheet. This gives me a running list of changes to the item on that row.

The issue I'm having is copying the correct information. If no filters are on, it's fine. I copy the cells from the ActiveCell.Row - 1. Once the code has run, it then moves up a row to the one they were on.

If a filter is on, however, it's not working correctly. Enter moves the cursor down, but there could be a hidden row on the ActiveCell.Row - 1, so it's counting that, rather than the visible row it's just moved down from. For example, they could edit row 50 and Enter moves down. If a filter is on, the next row down might be 261, so it's looking at the hidden 260 instead of 50.

How do I reference the right row, when Enter moves down one row, but there's a filter on? I hope that makes sense! Thanks in advance.

Comment: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) gives you details but you get an object in `Worksheet_Change ` called `Target` that is the cell that was changed

Comment: Please, edit your question and post the code you use. It is easier to show you what to be adapted than keeping a theory about a possible solution... What "Once the code has run, **it** then moves up a row to the one they were on" should mean?  What **it** are you referring to? The `Change` event code? If so, **how does it do that**?

Comment: You can change the excel default behaviour between enter finishing editing and moving down one cell to finishing editing AND staying in the same cell. Or you can move left, right or up as you wish.

Comment: @Solar Mike I think it is not a matter of settings. It looks that his existing code (looking to be secret...) moves the cursor up. But this **up** behaves differently in case of a filtered range. It is not complicated to make it jump to the previous discontinuous range row, but neither so simple for somebody not skilled. That's why I suggested to show his code and try correcting it in terms of cursor jumping wherever he needs...

Comment: @FaneDuru so if the cursor stays in the original cell there is no problem. Won’t be selecting a "filtered" cell on any other row…

Comment: Of course, but it looks that the problem stays in this statement: **"Once the code has run, it then moves up a row to the one they were on"**... I asked above about its meaning but no any clarification... Probably, his code has a final line 'Target.Offset(-1).select`. Why that? I have no any idea...